# differences in text and size in Firefox vs. Chrome and Safari with CSS reset

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts, safari, reset

I have been working on the Eric Meyer CSS Reset. 
I have a site that is text heavy.
The reset works for the margins. But it hasn't been working for font and font size. 
Firefox seems to make all text smaller even though I have a reset in place.
Is there any way to fix this in the CSS code?

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
} 
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


#box {
    background-color: #0F3;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: And if there is something I'm blatently missing, please point it out.